# Grid layout button sizing issues

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout, codenameone

button img size in the grid layout doesnt change whatever I do. Following is my code. if i scale the placeholder it hav no effect as well. The space that takes by padding and margin stays when i set padding and margin to zero as well. How can i make it compact and get rid of that gap between images..

```
        GridLayout gr = new GridLayout(1,2);
        gr.setAutoFit(true);
        Container grid = new Container(gr);
        grid.setUIID("containerGridImgGallery");
        grid.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        grid.getAllStyles().setMargin(0,0,0,0);
        f.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER,grid);

        placeholder = (EncodedImage) r.getImage("switch_on.png");
        //if I change the scaled value of placeholder, the img size doesnt change in the grid  eg scaledEncoded(screenWidth / 3, screenWidth / 3) doesnt change the img size
        placeholder = placeholder.scaledEncoded((screenWidth / 2)-10, screenWidth / 3);

        EncodedImage a = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder , galleryPhotoTitle + offset + imageId, galleryPhotoUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
        final Button btn = new Button(a);
        btn.setUIID("galleryGridButton");
        btn.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        btn.getAllStyles().setMargin(0,0,0,0);
```

i need grid Layout here since i can set to gridLayout.autofit() in gridLayout which is what i just wanted to auto fit the images as per the screens.How can i fit the grid cells to that of the button inside it? can i set the size of the grid?

updates:

//how to use scaleImageLabel in button? i got it work somehow but not correctly i guess

```
EncodedImage a = URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, galleryPhotoTitle + offset + imageId, galleryPhotoUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
final Button btn = new Button(a);
Image abc = btn.getIcon();
ScaleImageLabel scaledPlaceholder = new ScaleImageLabel(abc);
Container imageHolder = new Container();
imageHolder.addComponent(btn);
btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,1));
imageHolder.addComponent(scaledPlaceholder);
imageHolder.setLeadComponent(btn);
grid.addComponent(i, imageHolder);
```

i have a couple of questions: 
1)why can't i set the uiid of scaledPlaceholder above (ScaledImageLabel)
it takes some of padding & margins which i want to remove. If i set uiid the images
do not appear.

2)how does setBackgroundType() work? it doesnot take setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT).

3)And most importantly how can i fit the images in the grid maintaining the aspect ratio?
if i do smth like - abc = abc.scaled(230, 336);
It fits in the grid but doesnt keep the aspect ratio of the image.

Updates 1:

```
EncodedImage a = URLImage.createToStorage(largePlaceholder, galleryPhotoTitle + offset + imageId, galleryPhotoUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
ScaleImageButton scaleImageButton = new ScaleImageButton(a);
scaleImageButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //......
            }
        });
        grid.addComponent(i, btn);
```

exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at userclasses.StateMachine$ScaleImageButton.calcPreferredSize(StateMachine.java:500)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSizeImpl(Component.java:1930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSize(Component.java:1965)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredSize(Component.java:752)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredW(Component.java:832)
    at com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout.getPreferredSize(GridLayout.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.calcPreferredSize(Container.java:1793)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSizeImpl(Component.java:1930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSize(Component.java:1965)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredSize(Component.java:752)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredW(Component.java:832)
    at com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout.getPreferredSize(GridLayout.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.calcPreferredSize(Container.java:1793)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.calcScrollSize(Component.java:782)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getScrollDimension(Component.java:769)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.isScrollableY(Container.java:1873)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.isScrollable(Component.java:1686)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.isScrollable(Form.java:3058)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.checkAnimation(Component.java:3802)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.initComponentImpl(Component.java:4209)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.initComponentImpl(Container.java:843)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.initComponentImpl(Form.java:1608)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.setCurrent(Display.java:1332)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.show(Form.java:1588)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.show(Form.java:1566)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2515)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2561)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.showGalleryImage(StateMachine.java:159)
    at userclasses.StateMachine$1.lambda$readResponse$0(StateMachine.java:136)
    at userclasses.StateMachine$1$$Lambda$17/1247957021.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:345)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:397)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:428)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.pointerReleased(Button.java:516)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2560)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.pointerReleased(Form.java:2496)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.pointerReleased(Component.java:3108)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.handleEvent(Display.java:2017)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1065)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:994)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

error occured in here

```
 @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            Image i = getIcon();
            Style s = getStyle();
         //error occured here
            return new Dimension(i.getWidth() + s.getPaddingLeft(false) + s.getPaddingRight(false), i.getHeight()
                    + s.getPaddingTop() + s.getPaddingBottom());
        }
```

One more thing if i use label instead of btn it works fine but same doesnt work in case of button why is that?

Update 2: after adding getIconFromState method, blank form is displayed - same old problem and if null checker is removed, following error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:100)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1149)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:966)
    at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at userclasses.StateMachine$ScaleImageButton.calcPreferredSize(StateMachine.java:303)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSizeImpl(Component.java:1930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSize(Component.java:1965)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredSize(Component.java:752)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredW(Component.java:832)
    at com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout.getPreferredSize(GridLayout.java:153)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.calcPreferredSize(Container.java:1793)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSizeImpl(Component.java:1930)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.preferredSize(Component.java:1965)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredSize(Component.java:752)
    at com.codename1.ui.Component.getPreferredH(Component.java:842)
    at com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout.layoutContainer(BoxLayout.java:91)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1366)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1358)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1371)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.layoutContainer(Container.java:1358)
    at com.codename1.ui.Container.revalidate(Container.java:1006)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.setFocused(Form.java:1922)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.initFocused(Form.java:1553)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.show(Form.java:1584)
    at com.codename1.ui.Form.show(Form.java:1566)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2515)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder.showForm(UIBuilder.java:2561)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.startApp(StateMachineBase.java:56)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:31)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:98)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:51)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:23)
    ... 9 more
```

Update 3:
screenshot looks like this now:
portrait:

[image]

landscape: 
[image]

However if i go to landscape mode from portrait mode and again to portrait mode the images get adjusted as expected but i can still see the thin duplicate image portion there as well.

screenshot going from portrait to landscape and again to portrait:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once the images are downloaded and match the placeholder size they are stored/cached in the system. Since [Label](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Label.html) (or [Button](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Button.html) that derives it) doesn't scale the icon image this won't change.

Changing the placeholder size after downloading won't have an effect either.

For 3.3 we introduced a new [ScaleImageLabel](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/ScaleImageLabel.html) class that should allow the label to scale to take up the additional space in such a situation. Notice that artifacts may apply due to scaling.

Since you need a `Button` and not a label try something like this:

```
public class ScaleImageButton extends Button {

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScaleImageButton() {
        setUIID("Label");
        setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
        setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
    }

    /**
     * Create a version with the given image
     * @param i image
     */
    public ScaleImageButton(Image i) {
        setUIID("Label");
        setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
        setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
        setIcon(i);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the behavior of the background to one of Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT,
     * Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL, Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALE
     * @param behavior the background behavior
     */
    public void setBackgroundType(byte behavior) {
        getUnselectedStyle().setBackgroundType(behavior);
        getSelectedStyle().setBackgroundType(behavior);
        getPressedStyle().setBackgroundType(behavior);
    }

    public byte getBackgroundType() {
        return getUnselectedStyle().getBackgroundType();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        Image i = getIcon();
        if(i == null) {
            return new Dimension();
        }
        Style s = getStyle();
        return new Dimension(i.getWidth() + s.getPaddingLeft(false) + s.getPaddingRight(false), i.getHeight() +
                s.getPaddingTop() + s.getPaddingBottom());
    }


    public void setIcon(Image i) {
        getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(i);
        getSelectedStyle().setBgImage(i);
        getPressedStyle().setBgImage(i);
    }

    public Image getIcon() {
        return getUnselectedStyle().getBgImage();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
    }

    @Override
    public Image getIconFromState() {
        return getIcon();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUIID(String id) {
        Image icon = getIcon();
        super.setUIID(id); 
        setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Anyway can i make it work by twisting anything until 3.3 is released?

Comment: 3.3 was released last week.

Comment: how to use scaleImageLabel in button? i got it work somehow but not correctly i guess. I have updated what i have done so far in the question above but it doesnot work fine.

Comment: My original response assumed label. Since you need a button my revised response should include that.

Comment: I cannot stil use it in button since scaleImageLabel extends Label how can I use it in button. I need action listener in that image as well

Comment: Forgot to fix the extends statement on the top

Comment: it gives exception in this line:
return new Dimension(i.getWidth() + s.getPaddingLeft(false) + s.getPaddingRight(false), i.getHeight()
                    + s.getPaddingTop() + s.getPaddingBottom());
I've updated what i had done above in question as Update 1

Comment: In calcPreferredSize() method, this line Image i = getIcon(); gives null although there are images in the button. But if i extend ScaleImageButton class to Label, it gives the image values but for the button it always gives null.

Comment: `getIcon` can't return null only something within `getIcon` can return null so I need the exact line that fails.

Comment: In the constructor here: public ScaleImageButton(Image i) {}, it gives the value of encoded images as "com.codename1.ui.URLImage@68104944" and so on but image gets null here: protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {Image i = getIcon();}.I am sharing the project with button: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8OHhRelNxOWRUZEU/view?usp=sharing" and with label: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8ajRWVHFIWFh6VUU/view?usp=sharing". Please hav a look

Comment: I updated the `calcPreferredSize` method a while back and posted a comment that I updated the code. Notice that it differs from your method.

Comment: i think you checked the one with label, i have given the link of button also, there calcPreferredSize is same as u mentioned
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ATnICIY2S8OHhRelNxOWRUZEU/view

Comment: Don't bother with drive links. We don't download projects from users as we only have 20 work hours per day. I'm only looking at what you posted in the question which is incorrect.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. In the comment i didnt post all the code, i just mentioned the issue there. Actually I have exactly copied what you updated above

Comment: So where is it failing exactly now?

Comment: In the "Image i = getIcon();" line of calcPrefferedSize it always gives null  although there is images (encoded) in the constructor of scaleImageButton class

Comment: That doesn't matter since the next line is a null check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102657/discussion-between-beck-and-shai-almog).

Comment: there is a blank image shown in the form, i think it is due to that null value, isnt it? If it is not null as i checked by extending label instead of button in the ScaleImageButton class, the images are shown in the form. the null checker always return the null image with dimension null as well, so the form is blank. What might be the problem?

Comment: I see another issue. Added the `getIconFromState` to the bottom of the class

Comment: Uffff same problem again - blank form. if i remove null checker in calcPreferred method, it shows exception that are a bit different from previous. I have updated it above as update 2.

Comment: I see a bug there. It should be fixed in the next update. In that case you don't actually need my code as there will be a builtin `ScaleImageButton` that will work.

Comment: when will next update release? are you planning to do it anytime soon? i have crossed my deadline for the app, everything is done but this one. So i am eagerly waiting. thankyou btw.

Comment: Thinking about this again there is a workaround. I edited the source to workaround the issue.

Comment: thanks now the btn images are displayed but it is shown twice like refllected images. i have kept the screenshot above.